# Why doesn't this code work correctly? (C++)

Tags: c++

If I input this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{

int input, qty, min, max;
bool validity = 1;

cout << "How many integers would you like to enter? \n";
cin >> qty;

if (qty <= 0)
    cout << "Please enter a positive number\n";

else
{
    cout << "Please enter " << qty << " integers:" << endl;

    for (int x=0; x < qty; x++)
    {
        cin >> input;

        if (input > max)
            max = input;

        if (input < min)
            min = input;

    }

}


if (validity)
{
    cout << "Minimum: " << min << endl;
    cout << "Maximum: " << max << endl;
}


return 0;
}
```

It works as expected.

But if I have this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()

{

int input, qty, min, max;
bool validity = 1;

cout << "How many integers would you like to enter? \n";
cin >> qty;

if (qty <= 0)
    cout << "Please enter a positive number\n";

else
{
    cout << "Please enter " << qty << " integers:" << endl;

    for (int x=0; x < qty; x++)
    {
        cin >> input;

        if (input > max)
            max = input;

        if (input < min)
            min = input;

    }

}

if (max > 2147483646)
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid value for integers." << endl;
    validity = 0;
}

if (min < -2147483647)
{
    cout << "Please enter a valid value for integers." << endl;
    validity = 0;
}

if (validity)
{
    cout << "Minimum: " << min << endl;
    cout << "Maximum: " << max << endl;
}


return 0;
}
```

It gives me erroneous values.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated. (I'm a noob btw). Adding a little text here so that I can post this question.............................

Comment: I get [helpful compiler warnings](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d634c21f4b7f180).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

max and min are **uninitialized**. In C++, this means the values can be anything at all, unless in say Java where primitives are auto-initialized to 0.

One way to fix is to set a first flag, and set max and min the the first value entered.

```
bool first = true;
for (int x=0; x < qty; x++)
{
    cin >> input;

    if( first )
    {
        max = input;
        min = input;
        first = false;
    }
    if (input > max)
        max = input;

    if (input < min)
        min = input;

}
```

Here's what I mean by **uninitialized**. When starting up, min and max can be anything. Anything at all. Try it by printing out the value of min and max before your loop. It should (could) be different every time you run the program. Basically the value depends on what data was in that memory location the last time it was used.

So the `if( input > max)` is checking to see if input is greater than some random number between -2billion and 2 billion. (not useful). The `first` flag I put in there initializes `min`/`max` in the first iteration of the for loop, or the first value entered by the user, which is guaranteed to be both the min and the max of the entered value since it's the only entered value.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it :)

Comment: w00t! glad to help. Also you should put curly braces {} after all if-statements, even the one-liners. It'll save you a lot of headache in the long run. Good luck!

Comment: *In C++, this means the values can be anything at all*. Actually, using un-initialized variables is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so anything can happen (including crashes etc). Usually compilers just use whatever that's stored at that memory location, but one shouldn't rely on this.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. Btw, I wanted to know exactly what is going on with what you added. Can you explain further?

Comment: Sure. When starting up, min and max can be *anything*. Try it by printing out he value of min and max before your loop. It should (could) be different every time you run the program. So the if( input > max) is checking to see if input is greater than some random number between -2billion and 2 billion. (not useful). The 'first' flag I put in there initializes min/max in the first iteration of the for loop, or the first value entered by the user, which is guaranteed to be both the min and the max of the entered value since it's the only entered value.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got a better understanding now. :)

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus The description you provided really should be reworked into your answer.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Good call. Done.